# Structured data implementation using GTM (removal of old codes)

Tags: seo, google-tag-manager, json-ld

Consider we have created structured data using JSON-LD. After coming to know that we can do it using Google Tag Manager (GTM). We are planning to do it using GTM.

What measures & precautions we need to take now?

And also some doubts:

- 1) Can we remove old codes? If removed, will it affect our SEO or traffic?
- 2) Do we need to remove old codes?
- 3) Can we keep both codes? (using GTM & old codes)
- 4) What's the best practice?
- 5) Will GTM helps to reduce load on website? (less codes on website)

Comment: Structured data doesn't help with search engine rankings.  The only way it affects traffic is if you get a rich snippet that looks appealing to visitors and increases your click through rate.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing **structured data using GTM is not recommended**, even John Mueller from Google said He wouldn't rely on It (see https://twitter.com/thisisdelbert/status/1017098840422244352). The reason why is, because GTM is rendered via JavaScript and Google could have troubles with the rendering.

Plus, If you already have your structured data implemented using JSON-LD, why would you change It? It is the best approach you can do, because It is hardcoded in HTML and no JS is needed to be rendered.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Tomas. But many say that inserting structured data via GTM will help to reduce the load on server. Is it correct?

Comment: @samp I can't think about a case in which this would be true... Don't decide according to that statement.